# JQueryMobile ScrollView: Fire event when user scrolls

Tags: jquery-mobile, scrollview

I am using the JQueryMobile framework and the ScrollView component http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/.

Is there a way to receive an event when the user begins to scroll?
Unfortunatley I couldn't find a hint searching the docs and the internet

Answer (score 0):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

> **Scroll events**
>   ***scrollstart*** 
> Triggers when a scroll begins. Note that iOS devices freeze DOM manipulation during scroll, queuing them to apply when the
>   scroll finishes. We're currently investigating ways to allow DOM
>   manipulations to apply before a scroll starts.
>   ***scrollstop*** 
> Triggers when a scroll finishes.